# Nodejs publisher and subscriber in rabbitmq

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, rabbitmq

Hello folks I am stuck in a problem I will start by explaining what I am doing,

I have created 2 nodejs server one is publisher and other is subscriber and both servers would perform a math task like addition and multiplication

So i have created a rest api for addition and multiplication I am also getting the desired result if i start publisher and subscriber server and hit the addition / multiplication endpoint I am getting the desired result at the subscriber end

But I am not getting the idea of how can I create 2 copies of publisher and 3 copies of sub-worker/subscriber where pub1 and pub2 status will be different and upon completion the worker now has to inform the publishers about the result

Also it should tell all the past tasks and their result or pending status to publisher  and pub server should keep task list in local temp file

we can also use docker to create multiple copies but dont have idea how to do it ?

I am also sharing my code with you all

Any help with example would be appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Publisher.js file

```js
const express = require("express");
const amqp = require("amqplib");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
let channel, connection;
app.use(express.json());



app.get("/math-task/sum", (req, res) => {
  let inputOfA = parseInt(req.body.a);
  let inputOfB = parseInt(req.body.b);
  let sum = Number(inputOfA + inputOfB);
  sendData(sum); // pass the data to the function we defined
  console.log("A message is sent to queue");
  res.send("Message Sent For Addition:" + Number(sum)); //response to the API request
});

app.get("/math-task/mul", (req, res) => {
  let inputOfA = parseInt(req.body.a);
  let inputOfB = parseInt(req.body.b);
  let product = Number(inputOfA * inputOfB);
  sendData(product); // pass the data to the function we defined
  console.log("A message is sent to queue");
  res.send("Message Sent For Multiplication:" + Number(product)); //response to the API request
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Server running at port " + PORT));

async function connectQueue() {
  try {
    connection = await amqp.connect("amqp://localhost:5672");
    channel = await connection.createChannel();

    await channel.assertQueue("test-queue");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

async function sendData(data) {
  // send data to queue
  await channel.sendToQueue("test-queue", Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)));

  // close the channel and connection
  await channel.close();
  await connection.close();
}

connectQueue();
```

Subscriber.js file

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.use(express.json());
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Server running at port " + PORT));

const amqp = require("amqplib");
var channel, connection;
connectQueue()  // call the connect function
 
async function connectQueue() {
    try {
        connection = await amqp.connect("amqp://localhost:5672");
        channel    = await connection.createChannel()
        
        await channel.assertQueue("test-queue")
        
        channel.consume("test-queue", data => {
            console.log(`${Buffer.from(data.content)}`);
            channel.ack(data);
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use RPC for this kind of task which can be easily accomplished with callback queues in RabbitMQ. You can also find an example implementation here: [RabbitMQ RPC tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-javascript.html)

Basically what you want to do is to modify `sendData` to listen on the `replyTo` queue, if the message here is the response what you originally requested then it can resolve with the response. In the example this is tracked via `correlationId`.